# Swap strings in list into ints (Python)

Tags: python, arcpy

I'm trying to use `arcpy` to add a `list` of coordinates into `shapefile`, I'm using this code:

```
with open("pathtomyfile") as f1:
    for line in f1:
        str = line.split()
        mylist.append(str)
fc = "pathtomyshapefile"
cursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(fc, ["SHAPE@XY"])
for row in mylist:
    cursor.insertRow(row)
del cursor
```

However I'm encountering an error:

```
TypeError: sequence size must match size of the row
```

I've realised that this is caused by my list looking like:

```
[['1.222', '3.3333'],['333.444', '4444.5555']]
```

Instead of

```
[[1.222, 3.3333],[3.4444, 4.55555]]
```

Yet I have no clue how to fix it. Any help?

Comment: You can convert str to float by `mylist.append(list(map(float, str)))`

Comment: Unrelated to your question directly, note that you should avoid using `str` as a variable name, as it shadows the built-in function `str`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if you have the `list`:

```
l = [['1.222', '3.3333'],['333.444', '4444.5555']]
```

then what you are trying to do is convert each element to a `float`, this can be done with:

```
[[float(i) for i in j] for j in l]
```

which `outputs` a new `list` with contents:

```
[[1.222, 3.3333], [333.444, 4444.5555]]
```

---

Upon further inspection, it seems you may actually want the `output` of:

```
[[1.222, 3.3333],[3.4444, 4.55555]]
```

in this case, you can simply do:

```
[[float(i[i.index('.')-1:]) for i in j] for j in l]
```

or alternatively:

```
[[float(i) % 10 for i in j] for j in l]
```

but this second option leads to slightly off `floats` due to how Python handles them:

```
[[1.222, 3.3333], [3.444000000000017, 4.555500000000393]]
```